# Row ignores parent container padding

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to css, and there's a problem that should be fundamental, but  I don't seem to understand.

The problem is the row div of bootstrap container-fluid ignores padding set on the container-fluid div.

[image]

The inner border is the row and the outer border is the container-fluid with its margin and padding. The row seems to ignore the padding I set. There is nothing in my code setting this behavior.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-fluid {
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 3%;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.row {
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Any advice? I may not have perfect understanding off css, but I don't think this is something that should happen.

Comment: Use the built in bootstrap [***spacing***](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/) classes.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to do exactly what it should. Seems like you have mixed information about what margin and padding are. Maybe introducing some colors can clear things up a bit:

```css
.container-fluid {
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 3%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: orange;
}

.row {
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.col-sm {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the padding of the container (orange) applies, since both the row and col (blue and red) are not beside the container's inner borders. All the orange space is the padding, if we set padding to 0 there'll be no orange space.

EDIT: The lack of padding on the left and right of the orange box are due to bootstrap's own style rules that override ours.

Comment: I don't think orange space is padding. Why don't we have any orange space on the left and right side of the container div ?

Comment: @Psidom because due to bootstrap, there are extra negative margins at each side, if you inspect the blue box, you'll see -15px margins from each side, since it's the default `.row` behavior.

Comment: Hmm okay wonder why the outer div also has exactly 15px padding  on x-axis while the padding specified here was 3%.

Comment: @Psidom because CSS's default behavior is cascading, which means the style rule that comes last will be applied. In this case, bootstrap's style is applied last, so it'll override any rules we put. Unless we specify `!important` which is deferred anyways. Most likely bootstrap has classes that'll do what we want.